# SQL indexing on lines from joined table on each record from the original

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

Orders (o)

```
id | buyer  
1  | Joe  
2  | Ann  
3  | Sue
```

And Order_Items (oi)

```
id | master_record_id | stock number | qty  
1  | 1                | 1234         | 1  
2  | 1                | 7890         | 1  
3  | 1                | 4987         | 1  
4  | 2                | 1234         | 1  
5  | 2                | 7890         | 1  
6  | 2                | 4987         | 1  
7  | 3                | 1234         | 1  
8  | 3                | 7890         | 1  
9  | 3                | 4987         | 1
```

Table oi is dependable on orders by oi.master_record_id. Every record (id) in table oi is a unique one (there is no storing of which item this is on an order) so for the example I have 3 orders each with 3 lines and in table oi I have 9 records with ids 1 to 9.

My question is what query should I use to be able to export the orders (a line for each ordered item) where each oi has an index based on the order it is connected to:

Example output:

```
o.id | o.buyer | Required: Item on Order | oi.stock_number
1    | Joe     | 1                       | 1234
1    | Joe     | 2                       | 7890
1    | Joe     | 3                       | 4987
2    | Ann     | 1                       | 1234
2    | Ann     | 2                       | 7890
2    | Ann     | 3                       | 4987
3    | Sue     | 1                       | 1234
3    | Sue     | 2                       | 7890
3    | Sue     | 3                       | 4987
```

Many Thanks,

Dani

Comment: Is this mysql or sql server? They are NOT the same thing.

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server ?

Comment: You also should include your sample data, so we can produce your desire output.

Comment: That's a simple JOIN, eg select column1, column2 from table1 join table2 on table1.id = table2.t1_id

Comment: @jarlh they also need to add the row number in the output. ROW_NUMBER in sql server or ??? in mysql.

Comment: @SeanLange, alright, now I see what that "Required: Item on Order" column means.

Comment: @SeanLange `ROW_NUMBER` is a bunch of hacks in MySQL :D

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses guys, still very new, I will add sample data from the tables.

It is a MySQL server my mistake in choosing both

Comment: @Vatev I can barely spell mysql let alone use it so I have no clue but good to know it isn't great for ROW_NUMBER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id,buyer,Item_on_Order,stock_number
FROM
(SELECT O.`id` as id,
       O.`buyer` as buyer,
       (@row_num := IF(@category=O.`id`,@row_num+1,1)) as Item_on_Order,
       OI.`stock_number` as stock_number,
       @category := O.`id` AS Temp
FROM
Orders O
INNER JOIN Order_Items OI ON O.`id` = OI.`master_record_id`)T
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use "user variables" to generate row numbers.  Generate row numbers for your oi records and join with your Orders table to get your results.  [Here is a good blog post](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/) on how to achieve row numbering in MySQL.